# DRF use another model related fields in serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have 3 model **Product** - **Peyment** - **ProductDiscountControll**

`Peyment` and `ProductDiscountControll` have relation to column "`product`" to **Product** table

I want to have related ProductDiscountControll data like `discount` and `discount_code_precent` in peyment serilizer at get request.

In quest to do that, I tried following code in my `Serializer` Class

```
def get_product_discount(self, obj):
    return obj.product.product_discount.discount
```

but server says :

```
Field name `product_discount` is not valid for model `Peyment`.
```

I also tried like this way:

```
product_discount = ProductDiscountControllSerializer(many=True,read_only=True)
```

but `product_discount` not available in result

my view is look like this

```
class PeymentAPIView(APIView, mixins.DestroyModelMixin):
    permission_classes = [IsSafeGuard]

    def get(self, request):
        pay = Peyment.objects.filter(
            email=request.user.email,
            status=0,

        )
        serializer = PeymentSerializer(instance=pay, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

this is related Serializer class for get request:

```
class PeymentSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    producttitle = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_producttitle(self, obj):
        return obj.product.title

    productprice = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_productprice(self, obj):
        return obj.product.price


    def get_discount(self, obj):
        return obj.product_discount.discount
    #product_discount = ProductDiscountControllSerializer(many=True,read_only=True)


    class Meta:
        model = Peyment
        fields = [
            'product',
            'id',
            'producttitle',
            'productprice',
            'discount',
            'status',
            'user',
            'email',
            'transfer_id',
            'created_date',
            'updated_date',
        ]
        read_only_fields = ['email', 'user', 'producttitle', 'productprice']
```

this is Product model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_index=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    video_length = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    mini_description = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    full_description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    you_need = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True)
    you_learn = models.CharField(max_length=2000, null=True)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    video_level = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_to_custom_p,null=True,blank=True)
```

Peyment model:

```
class Peyment(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, to_field='product_id',
                                related_name='product_peyment')
    status = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    transfer_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

and discount model:

```
class ProductDiscountControll(models.Model):
    product = models.OneToOneField(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, to_field='product_id',
                                related_name='product_discount')
    discount = models.IntegerField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    discount_code = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    discount_code_precent = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=True, blank=True)
    updated_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

updated :

```
# product peyment
class PeymentSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    producttitle = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_producttitle(self, obj):
        return obj.product.title

    productprice = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_productprice(self, obj):
        return obj.product.price

    def get_discount(self, obj):
        serializer = ProductDiscountControllSerializer(obj.product.product_discount)
        return serializer.data


    class Meta:
        model = Peyment
        fields = [
            'product',
            'id',
            'producttitle',
            'productprice',
            'discount',
            'status',
            'user',
            'email',
            'transfer_id',
            'created_date',
            'updated_date',
        ]
        read_only_fields = ['email', 'user', 'producttitle', 'productprice']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use `product.product_discount` field name in serializer's method. To return serialized data you should pass this value to `ProductDiscountControllSerializer` and return `serializer.data`:

```
def get_discount(self, obj):
    discount = getattr(obj.product, 'product_discount', None)
    if discount: 
        serializer = ProductDiscountControllSerializer(discount)
        return serializer.data 
    return None
```

UPD

You should explicitly declare `discount` field in serializer with `SerializerMethodField` to use it in `fileds` list:

```
class PeymentSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    discount = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
```

Comment: thankyou for answer i tried your code but it say :
```Field name `discount` is not valid for model `Peyment`.
```

when i put `discount ` in fields

Comment: @moh in my code I never use `discount` field name. It's `product.product_discount`. Can you post updated serializer?

Comment: i posted entire updated serializer at bottom of question

Comment: @moh you need to add `discount` definition to the serializer. Check updates.

Comment: thanks , why server say :

`Product has no product_discount. `

Comment: @moh probaly current product dont have related discount. Try updated variant.